# Github and Heroku Cloning error - invalid path/syntax error

Tags: heroku, path, github, cloning

Here is my problem

I am using heroku to develop an app and I am using github along with it for a project.

Now when I try and use github(clone) without heroku to work on a different project it says...

```
michael@michael-HP-PavilionNotebook-PC:~$ 
michael@michael-HP-PavilionNotebook-PC:~$ 
michael@michael-HP-PavilionNotebook-PC:~$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/michael/.git/
michael@michael-HP-PavilionNotebook-PC:~$ ls
Desktop    Downloads         gifiniti       Music        Pictures  Templates  Ubuntu One
Documents  examples.desktop  gifinitiApr24  oldgifiniti  Public    tmp        Videos
michael@michael-HP-PavilionNotebook-PC:~$ git clone git@github.com:toadiferus/SecretTunnel
Cloning into SecretTunnel...

 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
michael@michael-HP-Pavilion-dv6700-Notebook-PC:~$
```

How would I resolve this error? Can't find any support online for this specific problem.
HOw can I change the syntax of the commands? I want to just clone a project from github not heroku.

THANKS!

- Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,  you don't need to `init` before you clone - init is used to turn a project folder into a git repository unless you really intended to turn your entire user directory into a git repo? I would suggest you delete the .git folder that would have been created from your doing this.

To be sure you're using the correct path go to your projects on github and use the icon that looks like a clipboard to copy the correct url to your clipboard, paste onto your command line and see what happens then.

I also don't understand why when you do a

```
git clone git@github.com:toadiferus/SecretTunnel
Cloning into SecretTunnel...
```

you get what looks like a Heroku push error??? Git clone from a github URL should simply clone the project from github to your local machine.

```
 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
```

Are you editing the output you are pasting?

Answer (score 1):

Your ~/.ssh/config may have been hijacked by if you used the heroku accounts plugin. Same thing happened to me. I removed the contents of my ssh config and all is well!

Comment: You seem to be missing the word for whatever could have hijacked their account (hijacked by ____ if you). This information is needed to help find root cause.

Answer (score 0):

The git url should have .git on the end, ie. `git@github.com:toadiferus/SecretTunnel.git`.

Comment: `git clone git@github.com:toadiferus/SecretTunnel.git` worked perfectly here.

Comment: so you tried it on your computer and it worked? Alright that helps me understand more where the problem is coming from, thanks!